# Как организовать циклическое выполнение скрипта в течение установленного времени?

Tags: php

Имеется грубо говоря, подобный скрипт
Мне нужно, чтобы он выполнялся 3 минуты ровно.

```
while(true){

  "тело скрипта"

  sleep(10);
}
```

Данный скрипт находится на хостинге.
Из документации PHP мы знаем:

`max_execution_time`

`set_time_limit()`

Не включает в ограничение Sleep, System, запросы http.

Если я поставлю лимиты на свой скрипт

```
max_execution_time 300;
```

```
set_time_limit(300);
```

От этого скрипт не будет выполняться 3 минуты, т.к. в команде есть Sleep();

`Server: nginx`

Но я не могу изменить настройки ngnix на хостинге

Я подумал, а вдруг можно запустить через ajax, установив timeout

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "https://url.con/ajax/test.php", // куда отправляем запрос
    error: function(){
        // будет вызвана в случае если пройдет 3 секунды, но ответа так и не было
      alert('no');
    },
    success: function(){
        // что-то делаем тут 
       alert('good');
    },
    timeout: 3000 // установка 3-х секундного тайм-аута
});
```

Но при выходе тайм аута, скрипт продолжает выполняться.

Что же делать в таком случае?

задача будет запускаться через Cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start = time();
$max_exec_time = 300;
while(true){

"тело скрипта"

  if(time()-$start>=$max_exec_time) break; else sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает